# redirect all non https request to https request by htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Hello all this is my htaccess and i have my https i want to redirect all the non https to https without affecting my get/post variables and anyother links just simply move the site to https

htaccess file

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   Options All -Indexes
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   ErrorDocument 403 /www.domain.com/error404.php
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 


   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

   # redirect /profile?eid=1 to /eid/1
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+profile(?:\.php)?\?(eid)=(\d+)\s [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

   # internally rewrite /eid/1 to /profile.php?eid=1
   RewriteRule ^(eid)/(\d+)$ profile.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]



   # redirect /dept?did=1 to /did/1
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dept(?:\.php)?\?(did)=(\d+)\s [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

   # internally rewrite /did/1 to /dept.php?did=1
   RewriteRule ^(did)/(\d+)$ dept.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+enterprise\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ enterprise.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

i have tried folling code to add to my htaccess file

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

but it redirects the site to error page but in https mode

i added the code after 403 error handler in htaccess page..

i am not soo good in htaccess please suggest me something..
just redirect the site on first attempt to https not on http

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be telling it to `redirect` using the `R flag` and provide a status `code` which will help your SEO. Make this rule your first rule

```
   Options All -Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   #all other rules below
```